# If $p$ is a prime number and $p\equiv 1(mod 4)$, (show that) there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^{2}+b^{2}=p$.

Tags: number-theory, congruences

I'm reading a book on number theory (*Theory of Numbers, Niven*), and yesterday I've stumbled upon a proof of the above lemma (*Lemma 2.13; page 54-55*). I've managed to wrap my mind around the proof from the book, but it is really unintuitive and hard to follow(at least for me). 
 
My question to you guys is do you know of any simpler and more intuitive proof of that particular lemma? 
 
edit: here's the link for the proof from the book

[image]

Comment: It is never the case that $p \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: is $(mod 4)$ what you want to say?

Comment: We don't know the proof you've seen. Presumably, you mean the proof by infinite descent? In that case, I don't know any other proof of that claim.

Comment: Hardy and Wright give a simple argument using lattices.  Still not entirely easy though.

Comment: Ok, can't say I'm a big fan of the proof you link to.  I posted my reconstruction of the lattice proof below.  Standard proofs, such as descent, can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the quick response. I'm not quite familiar with lattices, but I'm sure I will find something on the wikipedia page you gave a link to.

Comment: @EnverPodgorcevic The proof by infinite descent is the standard, without question.  And it is a crucial technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $-1$ is a square mod $p$. (This is proved quickly with Euler's Criterion, among other ways). So there is some $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, or rather $p \mid (x^2 + 1)$. Let's consider ourselves working within the Gaussian Integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which is a Euclidean Domain (since we have a division algorithm) and therefore has unique factorization.

Since $p \mid (x^2 + 1)$, we see that $p \mid (x+i)(x-i)$. Since we *do not* have $p \mid (x \pm i)$, we see that $p$ is not a Gaussian prime. Therefore $p$ factors nontrivially as $p = z_1z_2$ for some $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Now let's consider norms of $p = z_1z_2$. The norm of $p$ is $p^2$. So we have that $p^2 = N(z_1)N(z_2)$. Since neither $z_1$ nor $z_2$ are units, they each are forced to have norm $p$. Now since $z_1 \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, but is not in $\mathbb{Z}$ (since $p$ doesn't factor in $\mathbb{Z}$), we have that $z_1 = a + bi$ with $a,b \neq 0$. And the statement that the norm of $z_1$ is $p$ is exactly the statement that $a^2 + b^2 = p$.

Thus we have shown that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ means that $p$ can be written as a sum of two squares (in a completely nonconstructive way). $\diamondsuit$

Answer (score 0):

The lattice argument, as I recall it from Hardy and Wright:

As $p$ is 1 (mod 4) we can find $\lambda$ with $$\lambda^2 \equiv -1\,(mod\,p)$$
Define the lattice $\Lambda$ to be {$(m,n) \; m,n \in \mathbb Z\;\;m \equiv \lambda n \;(p)$} It is easy to convince yourself that the area of a fundamental parallelogram for $\Lambda$ is p (just count points in the lattice contained in a big circle).  Let P = (a,b) be a point in $\Lambda$ closest to the origin.  Then Q = (-b,a) is another minimal point in $\Lambda$ and it is easy to see that the Origin, P, and Q must be 3 vertices of a fundamental square for $\Lambda$.  But the area of that square is clearly $a^2+b^2$.